# Creating adjacency list from 2D array of ints

Tags: breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

I have run in to a roadblock when writing an algorithm to find:
a) the shortest bus route and
b) the route with the least switches.
I need to use BFS to solve it, but we are not given an adjacency list for each vertex, so I am confused as to how to make the adjacency list out of a 2D array of Integers, **where each number represents a bus stop, and each row is its own route:**

```
So, [1 2 3 4 5] is Route 1, 
    [6 7] is Route 2 etc. 
Also, the first station of each route is the next station 
the bus will reach from the last station of the route, 
so each route goes in circles: 
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 1 -> 2 -> ...
```

```
 1 2 3 4 5
 6 7
 8 7 4
 2 6
```

So far what I have is this:

```
public void fillAdjacencyList(int[][] routes){
        for(int i=0; i<routes.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<routes[i].length; j++){
                if(this.stop==routes[i][routes[i].length-1]){
                    BusStop temp=new BusStop(routes[i][0]);
                    this.next.add(temp);
                }else{
                    if(routes[i][j]==this.stop){
                        BusStop temp=new BusStop(routes[i][j+1]);
                        this.next.add(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        this.visited='*';
    }
```

The first vertex is initialized when i read the starting point from where I need to find the shortest bus route. Each vertex is defined as:

```
    int stop;
    ArrayList<BusStop> next;
    char visited;
    char created;
    int[] line;

    public BusStop(int st){
        this.stop=st;
        this.created='*';
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the 2D array of integers represents?

Answer (score 1):

The Python function below does the job. I made it in python so it's less verbose and (hopefully) easier to understand

```
def to_adj(routes):
    adj = { }
    for route in routes:
        for stop in route:
            if stop not in adj:
                adj[stop] = []

        for i in range(len(route)):
            adj[route[i]].append(route[(i+1) % len(route)])

    return adj
```